# How to correctly return api response when using retrofit in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, android-viewmodel

I am trying to make an app using mvvm design and in the repository class I am calling my api using retrofit.
I am getting correct response from my api and I want to return that response but while returning the data from my method the data value is null.
Please help me correct what I am doing wrong here.

My repository class:

```
public class UserStatusRepository {

private static ApiInterface apiInterface;
private static MutableLiveData<List<Submission>> submissions;
public UserStatusRepository() {
    apiInterface = RetrofitClient.getApiInterface();
    submissions = new MutableLiveData<>();
}


public LiveData<List<Submission>> loadUserStats(String params) {
    apiInterface.getUsersStatus("myapihere",params).enqueue(new Callback<UserStatusResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserStatusResponse> call, Response<UserStatusResponse> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                submissions.postValue(response.body().getSubmissions());
                //receiving correct response here
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserStatusResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            submissions.postValue(null);
        }
    });
    return submissions; // but while returning response is null
}

}
```

I think that I am returning the value before receiving the response from api so
What do I need to do so that while data(here data means submissions variable in my code) returned is not null?

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code

```
public class UserStatusRepository {
        
private static ApiInterface apiInterface;
public UserStatusRepository() {
            apiInterface = RetrofitClient.getApiInterface();
        }
        
        
        public LiveData<List<Submission>> loadUserStats(String params) {
        MutableLiveData<List<Submission>> submissions = new MutableLiveData<>();
            apiInterface.getUsersStatus("myapihere",params).enqueue(new Callback<UserStatusResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<UserStatusResponse> call, Response<UserStatusResponse> response) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                        submissions.setValue(response.body().getSubmissions());
                        //receiving correct response here
                    }
                }
        
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<UserStatusResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    submissions.setValue(null);
                }
            });
            return submissions; // but while returning response is null
        }
       }
```